# ActiveMQ single message consumed by multiple consumers

Tags: concurrency, activemq-classic, message-queue, producer-consumer

We are facing an issue where one message is consumed by two consumers from same queue. We want to restrict one message so that it can only be consumed by one consumer.

There is one producer application pushing the messages to queue named "Aeon," and the listener of this queue is dedicated to inserting a record. If the record already exists it will send a message to an "update" queue.

For the "update" queue we are running concurrently 10 consumers (same listener class with 10 threads configured).

**Example:**

Producer sends messages A1 to A10 to the "update" queue, message A6 is consumed by two consumers, and it hurts our business flow. We want to make sure that same message can not be consumed by two consumers.
Has any one faced this issue, and, if so, how did you fix it?

Consume code :

```
    @Autowired
ReconMessageProcessor reconMessageProcessor;
@Value("${recondataProcessorRunEnable}")
public Boolean recondataProcessorRunEnable = true;

public void onMessage(Message pMessage) {
    if (recondataProcessorRunEnable) {
        try {
            logger.info("RetryReconDataInsertMessageListener pMessage.getJMSCorrelationID() -->  " + pMessage.getJMSCorrelationID());
            logger.info("RetryReconDataInsertMessageListener pMessage.getJMSMessageID() -->  " + pMessage.getJMSMessageID());
            MessageEntity message = (MessageEntity)((ActiveMQObjectMessage) pMessage).getObject();
            String jsonMessage = message.getJsonString();
            reconMessageProcessor.processMessage(jsonMessage, "RetryReconDataInsertMessageListener");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //send mail about recon message receive failure
            logger.error("Exception has occured while executing ReconMessageListener. Error details is : " +
                e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        logger.info(" Value of recondataProcessorRunEnable is " + recondataProcessorRunEnable + " at property file. Please set it to true to enable recondataProcessor run");
    }

}
```

Comment: @JustinBertram : updated the question with consumer code.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: Hello @JustinBertram : we are using  apache-activemq-5.15